# C++ struct initialization with a function

Tags: c++, performance, file, struct, initialization

I'm dealing with the following situation:

```
Struct Data;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Data> DataPtr;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, DataPtr> DataPtrMap;

DataPtrMap data;
std::string file_path;
```

I need to create an empty `DataPtrMap` and initialize it from file with a function that takes the file path as an input. Essentially, this function reads the file line-by-line, creates a new `struct`, fills it with data and inserts it in the `unordered_map`. The `Data` structure contains just some integers and a couple of small matrices, and there can be up to a few thousands of them in the `unordered_map`. I'm wondering whether it's more efficient to pass a pointer to the (initially empty) data as input to the function as:

```
void loadData(DataPtrMap*, const std::string&);
loadData(&data, file_path);
```

or if it's better to directly return it from the function as:

```
DataPtrMap loadData(const std::string&);
data = loadData(file_path);
```

My intuition is that the second solution is much cleaner in terms of readability and return value optimization should avoid making a useless copy of the data when returning from the function. However, I would like to have the opinion of more expert coders.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Always write your code to prioritize readability. Premature optimization is just going to make your life harder when you have to go back and fix bugs in code from years prior. As a general rule, try to always use the most optimal "Big O" for the job, but don't worry about the performance of passing and returning from a function call: your compiler is always going to be able to do a better job than you, and I'd be surprised if on -O3 those don't get the same machine code.

Comment: Why is the pointer shared?

Comment: Start with the stupidest, simplest approach that A) Works and B) Stands a reasonable chance of meeting the performance requirements. If it meets the requirements, you're done. Move on to the next problem or go home and relax. If it doesn't, run the program in a profiler and see what's eating up most of your time. Don't waste your time with the little stuff. Focus on the pieces that  you can prove are using time that you don't absolutely have to use AND are worth the effort.

Comment: If the program spends 90% of it's on something you can't find any way to speed up, no other changes you make to the program are going to be noticeable.

Comment: Just to add another perspective, I work on perf sensitive code, and the death by 1000 cuts principle is real.  That is, things like extra copies of smallish data may never show up on a profile themselves, but taken in aggregate substantively slow the program down.  Our team has found that paying attention to these kinds of things as we write new code is much more efficient than having to fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the use of raw pointer in your case you can use references in your option1 :

```
void loadData(DataPtrMap&, const std::string&);
loadData(data, file_path);
```

With references the first option is clean and needs no more optimization to avoid unnecessary copy.

I like the syntax of option2 but your need to take care of optimizing copy. But like jfh said, optimization is the last step when coding, do not bother with that at the beginning

Comment: Hi @leJon, I didn't go for references since in general it seems a little bit less clear that the function actually modifies the data when you read the code. However, in this particular case where the function name is self-explaining, it could be an option. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of references for that same reason.  I prefer to know at the call site when I'm handing out a mutable copy of data.